# How to align this logo at the top of the page using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Hi,
I want the logo 'Abyk Deco' to stay at the top of the page, but it's now centered along with the two heading text. How can I align this at the top using flexbox? I've tried this code.

```
<body>
<div class="banner">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">Abyk<span id="red">Deco<span></a></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="heading">
        <h1>ABYK DECO</h1>
        <h4>We make your dream home come true!</h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .banner{
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/1.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;  
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}  

.logo{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}   

.logo a{
    color: #fff;
}

#red{
    color: red;
}

.heading{
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.heading h1{
    font-size: 4.5em;
}

.heading h4{
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

How can I align the logo to the top while the heading texts stay at the center? I prefer to use flexbox to solve this problem. Thank You.

Comment: I made a minor update to my 2nd sample, removing the logo's `h1`'s bottom margin, so it visually appears in the middle

Comment: Let me know if my answer were helpful and can be accepted? ... and if not, is there something I can adjust, add or explain?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: gray;
}

.logo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <p>Text something </p>
    <p>Something else </p>
    <p>What else?</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Try to use this.

Comment: It works when just the logo is present. But when I add the heading text in the html, the alignment goes off

Comment: @SakirInteser I edited.

Answer (score 1):

The main trick here to be able put the `logo` at the top and `heading` in the center of the viewport, is to use the `::after` pseudo element to match the `logo` and then add this rule and make them equal high by setting *flex-grow* to 1 and *flex-basis* to 0

```
.logo, .heading, .banner::after {
  content: '';                      /*  for the pseudo to render  */
  flex: 1 1 0;                      /*  grow/shrink equal based on zero content  */
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.banner {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x100/555);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.logo a {
  color: #fff;
}

#red {
  color: red;
}

.heading {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.heading h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  margin: 0;                        /*  remove default margin  */
}

.heading h4 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;                        /*  remove default margin  */
}

.logo, .heading, .banner::after {
  content: '';                      /*  for the pseudo to render  */
  flex: 1 1 0;                      /*  grow/shrink equal based on zero content  */
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1><a href="#">Abyk<span id="red">Deco</span></a></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="heading">
    <h1>ABYK DECO</h1>
    <h4>We make your dream home come true!</h4>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

If the `heading` should be in the center of the space left (between the end of the `logo` and page bottom), use auto margin on the `heading`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.banner {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/300x100/555);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.logo h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;                 /*  remove default margin  */
}

.logo a {
  color: #fff;
}

#red {
  color: red;
}

.heading {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.heading h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  margin: 0;                        /*  remove default margin  */
}

.heading h4 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;                        /*  remove default margin  */
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1><a href="#">Abyk<span id="red">Deco</span></a></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="heading">
    <h1>ABYK DECO</h1>
    <h4>We make your dream home come true!</h4>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `align-items` to `flex-start`

```
.banner{
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/1.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;  
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: not working. still at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following styles from `banner` class would do.

```
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Add the following styles to `logo` class

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.banner {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://images.designtrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/06084012/Dark-Brown-Bricks-Backgroud.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.logo a {
  color: #fff;
}

#red {
  color: red;
}

.heading {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.heading h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
}

.heading h4 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1><a href="#">Abyk<span id="red">Deco<span></a></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="heading">
    <h1>ABYK DECO</h1>
    <h4>We make your dream home come true!</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working, everything is at the top now

Comment: @SakirInteser : Please run the code snippet. I hope it works well in the snippet.

Comment: I want the logo to be centered horizontally too.

Comment: @SakirInteser : Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @SakirInteser: Is this working now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `flex-grow: 1;` to the `.heading`, `align-self: center;` to the `.logo` and remove `margin-top` from the `.logo H1` (optional)

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="logo">
      <h1><a href="#">Abyk<span id="red">Deco<span></a></h1>
  </div>

<div class="heading">
    <h1>ABYK DECO</h1>
    <h4>We make your dream home come true!</h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner{
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100vh;
   background-image: url(../img/1.jpeg);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center top;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   display: flex;  
   flex-direction: column;
 }  

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  align-self: center; /*added*/
}   

 .logo a{
   color: #fff;
 }

 .logo H1 { /*added*/
   margin-top: 0;
}

#red{
   color: red;
}

.heading {
   font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
   color: #fff;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-grow: 1; /*added*/
}

.heading h1{
  font-size: 4.5em;
}

.heading h4{
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

[Code exmaple](https://jsfiddle.net/zoy34g68/) on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add `margin: 0 auto auto auto;` to both your `.logo` and `.heading`

*p.s. I have minimize the font size so that you can see the preview properly in the code snippet or just check out the preview on full screen*

```css
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  background:grey;
  height:100%;
}
.banner{
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/1.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;  
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}  

.logo{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto auto auto;

}   

.logo a{
    color: #fff;
}

#red{
    color: red;
}

.heading{
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto auto auto;
}

.heading h1{
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}

.heading h4{
    font-size: 1.3em;
}



.logo h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.heading h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="#">Abyk<span id="red">Deco<span></a></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="heading">
        <h1>ABYK DECO</h1>
        <h4>We make your dream home come true!</h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't center it perfect in the viewport's middle, though it _looks_ like it does, because of the kept bottom margin on the `heading`'s `h4`. If to really center it, that bottom margin needs to match the `header`'s half height.

Comment: can the `.logo` be outside the `.banner` class? If yes then you can create two display:flex and position them separately. It is due to the nature of flex, the divs will always be position relatively to the adjacent divs, regardless is aligning or justifying center. Another solution will be using position absolute.

Comment: I am not the asker, and you can do this without absolute positioning, which I showed in my answer. I just wanted to notify you that this doesn't work 100%. And when using auto margins, as you can see in my 2nd sample, it is only needed on the `heading`, and would need the same fix I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Got it now, agreed, I can see that you are centering base using 3 vertically centered columns. and the second column will always centered itself